# Can I create a JSVGCanvas without an svg file?

Tags: java, swing, svg, jython, batik

Looking through the [documentation for `JSVGCanvas`](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/swing/JSVGCanvas.html#JSVGCanvas(org.apache.batik.swing.svg.SVGUserAgent,%20boolean,%20boolean)), it seems like I might not be able to do this. However, it makes a lot of sense for this to be possible. How can I create a `JSVGCanvas` from a `String` variable instead of a `File`?

My idea is that I could do something like the following:

```
String svg = "svg data";
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JSVGCanvas canvas = new JSVGCanvas();
canvas.setContentsFromString(svg);
frame.add(canvas);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I know I could always create a temporary file and set the contents of the `JSVGCanvas` from the file, but I'd rather avoid that. Could I perhaps extend `File` and override its methods?

<sub>Note: I am using Jython, but I think that this is relevant for Java as well, hence I'm using both tags. I'd prefer that a solution be in Java, but a Jython solution would work</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
SAXSVGDocumentFactory factory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
SVGDocument document = factory.createSVGDocument("", new ByteArrayInputStream(svg.getBytes("UTF-8")));

canvas.setSVGDocument(document);
```

This works by creating an `SVGDocument` via `SAXSVGDocumentFactory`. `SAXSVGDocumentFactory` has a method [`createSVGDocument(String, InputStream)`](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/anim/dom/SAXSVGDocumentFactory.html#createSVGDocument(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader)), where the string is supposed to be a URI to the file that the `InputStream` represents. However, we abuse that and give it an empty string, and make the `InputStream` a stream from our svg-data String.

Using `""` might throw an exception about their being no protocol, depending on the version of Batik. If that's the case, try `"file:///"`, that is, give it a URI that is a lie. You may want to use an actual URI; you'd need to figure out a valid one to give to Batik

Comment: On version 1.6 of Batik, this results in a "java.io.IOException: no protocol:" at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createDocument()

Comment: @tucuxi sounds like the uri needs more info. Maybe try something like `file:///` (perhaps with a fake path after

Comment: I can confirm that using "file:///" instead of "" works fine (batik 1.6 from Maven Central)

Comment: on batik 1.10 it works both with "" as well as "file:///"